# Необходимо передать id кнопки при нажатии на нее в input

Tags: javascript, jquery, форма

На сайте несколько кнопок, которые открывают одно модальное окно. Но кнопки с разным смысловым содержанием. Мне необходимо при нажатии на кнопку добавить её name или id в скрытое поле формы. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('input.hidden').val(this.id);
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Кнопка</button>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.overlay, .modal-close').click(function() {
  $('.modal, .overlay').removeClass('shown');
});

$('.load-modal-frame').click(function() {
  let id = this.id;
  $('.modal .modal-content').text(id);
  $('.overlay, .modal').addClass('shown');
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
.modal {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.modal .modal-close {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  stroke: black;
}

.modal iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 0;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
}

.modal.shown,
.overlay.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button-1" class="load-modal-frame">button-1</button>
<br>
<button id="button-2" class="load-modal-frame">button-2</button>

<div class="modal">
  <span class="modal-close">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 40 40">
    <path class="close-x" d="M 10,10 L 30,30 M 30,10 L 10,30" />
  </svg>
  </span>
  <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```